# cython code continues after prange returns value

Tags: parallel-processing, return, cython

Suppose i have the following function:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef bint test(np.int_t [:] values):
    cdef Py_ssize_t n_values = len(values)
    cdef int i
    for i in prange(n_values,nogil=True):
        if i ==0:
            return 0

    print 'test'
```

I run it like so:

```
In [1]: import algos

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: algos.test(np.array([1,2,3,1,4,5]))
test
Out[3]: False
```

Why is the function printing when it should have just exited without printing? Is there a way to have the function exit when it reaches the return?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation is clear that this is a bit of a minefield since there's no guarantee which iteration finishes first](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html#breaking-out-of-loops). I think the added complication that they don't make clear is that if the number of iterations is small enough then (provided one thread is done) you can also end up continuing as after the `prange` too, which is what you see.

What seems to work for me is to use the `else` clause of a loop, which only gets executed if it hasn't finished early:

```
for i in prange(n_values,nogil=True):
    # stuff ...
else:
    with gil:
        print "test"
```

A quick look at the C code suggests that this is putting appropriate checks in place and it should be reliable.

Comment: To be honest though, this looks a lot like a bug since it seems to happen with any sized `prange` so it might be worth reporting it. https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/